# Overwrite source_workload metric using istio operator

Tags: prometheus, metrics, istio, envoyproxy

I would like to overwrite the source_workload tag in the request_bytes_bucket metric due to high cardinality issues generated by a specific workload - I do not want to drop the source_workload tag as that will break Kiali functionality and affect other workloads that do not have this issue - I've tried using the following definition but this does not seem to be working, there doesnt appear to be many examples so I'm not sure if a ternary or regex can be used in this scenario:

```
apiVersion: install.istio.io/v1alpha1
kind: IstioOperator
metadata:
  name: istio
spec:
  values:
    telemetry:
      v2:
        prometheus:
          configOverride:
            inboundSidecar:
              metrics:
                - name: request_bytes_bucket
                  dimensions:
                    source_workload: "matches(istio_request_bytes_bucket.source_workload, \"source-workload-prefix-.*\") ? istio_request_bytes_bucket.source_app : istio_request_bytes_bucket.source_workload"
```

Comment: Which version of Kubernetes, istio and prometheus did you use and how did you set up the cluster? Did you use bare metal installation or some cloud providor? What do you mean by "this does not seem to be working"? Do you have any errors?

Comment: k8s: 1.18, istio: 1.9.1 running on EKS - no errors, it applies the enovy filter but does not affect any of the metrics

Comment: Did you know, you are using deprecated version of k8s? Did you use some tutorial to deploy or did you just try to create monitoring and have problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get this working I had to drop the 'istio' prefix, the 'bucket' suffix and add an additional set of single quotes around the value e.g.

```
values:
   telemetry:
     enabled: true
     v2:
       enabled: true
       prometheus:
         configOverride:
           inboundSidecar:
             stat_prefix: istio
             metrics:
               - name: request_bytes
                 dimensions:
                  source_workload: "'test'"
```